# How can I install KVM on Ubuntu 12.04 when I have a VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm

I have a Windows 8 machine. 
Now, I need to use KVM on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. To avoid to make a disk partition, I have installed VirtualBox and run on it Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as Virtual Machine.
Now, I want to install and configure KVM on it. I'm following this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/

but, when I execute this command:

```
egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo
```

I get

> 0

I read that

> "A 0 indicates that your CPU doesn’t support hardware virtualization"

I have seen "virtualbox setting" and I note that, in the "System" tab, I have marked the hardware virtualization options. Why I get this value when I run that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get precisely the same results when running **Ubuntu 14.04** LTS as guest Virtual Machine within Hyper-v on Windows 8.1.

I'm also very interested in hearing feedback. KVM shows as being installed in /usr/bin.  However, Android Studio is looking for it in /dev.  To trick it, I created a symbolic link in /dev pointing to `/usr/bin/kvm`.  Running against this setup returns a similar message of:

Could not extract KVM version: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Answer (score 1):

To help diagnose one of the issues.. do not create a symbolic link. The VM guest must have virtualization enabled.

For e.g in VMWare, in the VM iamge settings... see the `Hardware` `Processor` settings has `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI` enabled

Answer (score 1):

so you put a virtual environment inside a virtual environment on a windows machine. That doesn't make much sense.

You have already installed Ubuntu in Virtualbox, so it is not directly using the CPU (but the virtualized CPU provided by Virtualbox). 
egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo  won't give you the results of the host CPU now.
check the first lines of this and you'll see what I mean:
    cat /proc/cpuinfo